# Generics methods: static vs NON-static

Tags: java, generics, methods

Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) java tutorial:

> For static generic methods, the type parameter section must appear
>   before the method's return type.

Is it not true for NON-static generic method? If not what's the NON-static generic method syntax? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax for declaring non-static generic methods is the same as for static methods, just without the `static` keyword: generic type parameters are placed before the return type.

```
class Example {
     public <E> void method(E param) { }
}
```

Non-static methods may also use the generic type parameter of the enclosing class, like below. These are not considered generic methods; a [generic method is one that declares type parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4).

```
class Example<T> {
     // Not a generic method!
     public void method(T param) { }
}
```

Comment: "Non-static generic methods may use the generic type parameter of the enclosing class." Then they are NOT *generic methods*. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4

Comment: Thanks @newacct, I was confused about the definition of generic methods.

Answer (score 7):

This is true for any generic methods.

```
public <T> T f() {
    return this.<T> f();
}
```

Comment: you should *really* get a warning here, since you are actually hiding `<T>` with `T`

Answer (score 2):

That statement is true for all generic methods, because that is the *very definition* of a generic method -- a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4) is one that declares type parameters.